# How to calculate P value in polychoric correlation

Tags: correlation, p-value, polychoric

I see that I can get polychoric correlation coefficients using package [girth](https://pypi.org/project/girth/).

I have following data:

```
y1 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]
y2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ]
```

I use the package to get polychoric correlation matrix:

```
data = np.array([y1, y2])
polychoric_corr = gcm.polychoric_correlation(data, start_val=0, stop_val=1)
print(polychoric_corr)
```

The output is:

```
[[1.         0.56250022]
 [0.56250022 1.        ]]
```

Hence, polychoric correlation coefficient is 0.56. How can I calculate P value (significance) for this? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I believe that p-values can be obtained from the `polycor` package

Comment: It will be best to post an answer with code and output to show how p-value can be obtained from polycor package.